# In this code I got Cannot resolve symbol R

Tags: java, android

I used the GitHub time picker dialog library and I got an error "Can not find symbol R".

1) The library I used.

```
implementation 'com.kovachcode:timePickerWithSeconds:1.0.1'
```

2) The error line code is below.

```
setButton(context.getText(R.string.time_set), this);  // in this line
    setButton2(context.getText(R.string.cancel), (OnClickListener) null);// in this line
    //setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_time);

    LayoutInflater inflater = 
            (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.time_picker_dialog, null);//in this line
    setView(view);
    mTimePicker = (TimePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.timePicker);//in this line
```

This file is also a read-only file and not editable. Please give me a solution.

3) These are all dependencies I used.

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.6'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1-rc1'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'
implementation 'info.androidhive:fontawesome:0.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.kovachcode:timePickerWithSeconds:1.0.1'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: Hi Arpit welcome to the SO Community.
The time picker dialog library that you used is causing you an error "Can not find symbol R"? and The code in the Library is not editable? is that is what you're asking?

Comment: Yes..I used github timepikerdialog with second dependency..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your manifest and add

```
tools:replace="android:icon, android:label, android:theme"
```

Answer (score 0):

import like this in your class.
    import com.yourpackage.R;

Answer (score 0):

it can be error on "time_picker_dialog.xml" file or any other xml file. Can you check it?

Comment: i checked my all xml file.. but there are no error found in xml.